# Hide App icon from its package Name

Tags: android

I am new to android. I want to hide other app icons from their package names. I get apps package name using this code

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> PackList = pm
        .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
for (int i = 0; i < PackList.size(); i++) {
    ApplicationInfo PackInfo = PackList.get(i);
    // if (((PackInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) !=
    // true) {

    appsList.add(new AppPojo(PackInfo
            .loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString(),
            PackInfo.packageName.toString(), "0"));
    // }
}
```

Give package name of a particular app, is it possible to hide its icon??

Comment: Do you want to hide the icon on the activity Title bar?

Comment: No from device menu which is displaying all app icons

Comment: Had you tried by removing the app icon from the menifest file? it could work. and also you can try by creating an application without a launcher icon. it could also work, well I am not so sure about it though. if it works just tell me.

Comment: Actually I don't want to hide my own app icon, rather I want to hide other application icons like icons of gallery or messages apps etc which are installed on android device.

Comment: hmmm, well, than @CommonsWare is right, only if you create your own Home Screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Give package name of a particular app, is it possible to hide its icon?

No. You are welcome to write your own home screen which filters out apps, but you cannot force other home screens, or anything else, from showing whatever they want.

Comment: @CommomsWare will you give some working link of hiding my own app from home screen without requiring reboot. I searched but all I get is that they require reboot for hiding your app icon.